# &sect; character kills nsxmlparser

Tags: iphone, special-characters, nsxmlparser

I've got an nsxmlparser. It works well enough, though I had to convert all the special characters coming into it into their coded equivalents: & had to be &amp;, " had to be &quot;, and so on. However, &sect; (§) kills it at parser:didStartElement.

Do you know a way around this? Naturally, I need the § characters to show up.

Comment: I found a way to brute force this: Have the server send "&amp;sect;" in place of "&sect;" and then just run the following line on the clientside: labelText = [labelText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&sect;" withString:@"§"]; I'd hope there's a more graceful way, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a workable answer in the comments to the question:

"Have the server send `"&amp;sect;"` in place of `"&sect;"` and then just run the following line on the clientside:

```
labelText = [labelText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&sect;" withString:@"§"];
```

I'd hope there's a more graceful way, though